# What HMM (Hidden Markov Models) libraries have good support for Python?

Tags: python, binding, hidden-markov-models

I'll have to train a HMM (Hidden Markov Models) system. I was told I could use [HTK](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/) or the [CSLU Toolkit](http://cslu.cse.ogi.edu/asr/). The first has a binding for Python, apparently, called [pyhtk](http://www.e-gymraeg.org/wispr/pyhtk.htm).

Have any of you used that binding? Would you recommend me to go for it? Are there other HMM libraries out there with better support for Python?

Thanks

Comment: What do you need this for? HTK has a pretty restrictive license model, i.e. you cannot distribute it.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. I'm needing this for some kind of project a professor would like me to do so, at first, that doesn't look like a problem. But anyway, I don't like having that sort of restrictions. Thanks for the input. I think HTK is not what I want. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a look at HTK for a while ago, but it did not seem that well maintained and also very targeted towards speech recognition. Another library that I would recommend you to look at is http://ghmm.org/ that contains python bindings, an EM-learner, and even a graphical editor some documentation. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try implementing your own HMM. It would provide you with much more flexibility, considering the fact that implementing a HMM is quite trivial.